# Mongo 3.2 join with specific item

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Imagine two collections in Mongo 3.2 called student and class.  What is the query that would return all student documents that are in a specific class.

The aggregate with $lookup seems to want to operate on all documents in the collection.  For instance returning all students in every class instead of the specific one.

**How can I request the resulting student documents that are in a specific class with id=23945647b27e7e652a9aeb65?**

Class:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("23945647b27e7e652a9aeb65"),  // Given this
    "name" : "Algebra",
    "students" : [ "13945647b27e7e65869aeb65", "03945647b27e7e65029aeb65" ]
}
```

Student:  // Return this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("13945647b27e7e65869aeb65"), 
    "name" : "foo"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("03945647b27e7e65029aeb65"), 
    "name" : "bar"
}
```

Some failed attempts:

```
db.student.aggregate([{$match:{"$ref": "class", "_id": ObjectId("23945647b27e7e652a9aeb65")}},{$lookup:{from: "class",localField:"students",foreignField: "_id", as: "stuffFromRight"}}}])


db.student.aggregate([{$lookup:{from: {"$ref": "class", "_id": ObjectId("23945647b27e7e652a9aeb65")},localField:"students",foreignField: "_id", as: "stuffFromRight"}}])
```

This one gets PARTIAL credit as it does do the correct lookup.  BUT, ..., it does not limit the result to the specific class I want.

```
db.student.aggregate([{$lookup:{from: "class",localField:"students",foreignField: "_id", as: "stuffFromRight"}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the example.

1. The type between the array in class and the student object itself is not the same.  You wouldn't be able to compare a string to an ObjectId and expect the desired result.
2. $lookup performs an $eq on the two fields.  In the example, that means that the lookup is trying to compare:

   ["13945647b27e7e65869aeb65","03945647b27e7e65029aeb65"] == ObjectId("13945647b27e7e65869aeb65")

Because of both of the points above, this query would fail and it would end up searching all the documents.

In order to use the students array from the class side, you would need to first fix the array to match type, then you would have to first unwind the array before performing a lookup.  Here is an example:

```
db.class.aggregate([ 
    {$match:{ "_id": ObjectId("23945647b27e7e652a9aeb65")}}, 
    {$unwind: "$students"},
    {$lookup: { from: "student", localField: "students", foreignField: "_id", as: "stuffFromRight"}} 
])
```

With the result above, you could then use a project to reduce it to only show the student records if you want to, but it may also be worth pulling the class and students together since you will likely need to query the class anyway in the output.

Comment: students is a hex string which is equivelent to "new ObjectId( hexStr )" but causes a empty result in the last lookup phase.  The unwind produces several copies of the class object but with and empty "stuffFromRight" field.

What is needed is a String->ObjectId transformation.

Comment: @redboy There is not an option in an aggregation to convert a string to ObjectId or vise versa.  Ultimately, the data needs to be fixed so that it has not lost it's type.  You may need to pull the students array into your application, then query the students once the types are correctly set on each element in the array of student ids.